# probability of 3rd chase being kill

Tags: probability

a wildlife study has found that a wolf pack is successful in killing one large animal for every 12 that it chases. a researcher has been observing this wolf pack.  he has data from 6 days of the pack hunting. what is the probability that on 2 of these days the first large animal killed is the 3rd one chased?

Comment: Exactly 2 or at least 2?

Answer (score 1):

P(first large animal killed on a day is the third one chased) = $\frac{11}{12}\frac{11}{12}\frac1{12}= p,\;$ say

Now apply the binomial distribution

P(This happens on $2$ of the $6$ days observed) = $\binom62\cdot p^2(1-p)^4$